# Kibana not showing monitoring data from external Elasticsearch node

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, monitoring

yesterday I setup a dedicated single monitoring node following [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/monitoring-production.html) guide.

I managed to fire up the new monitoring node with the same ES 6.6.0 version of the cluster, then added those lines to my elasticsearch.yml file on all ES cluster nodes :

```
xpack.monitoring.exporters:
  id1:
 type: http
  host: ["http://monitoring-node-ip-here:9200"]
```

Then restarted all nodes and Kibana (that is actually running in one of the node of the ES cluster).

Now I can see today monitoring data indices being sent to the new monitoring external node but Kibana is showing a "**You need to make some adjustments**" when accessing the "Monitoring" section.

```
We checked the  `cluster defaults`  settings for  `xpack.monitoring.exporters` , and found the 
reason:  `Remote exporters indicate a possible misconfiguration: id1`

Check that the intended exporters are enabled for sending statistics to the monitoring cluster, 
and that the monitoring cluster host matches the  `xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch`  setting in  
`kibana.yml`  to see monitoring data in this instance of Kibana.
```

I already checked that all nodes are pingable each other , also I don't have xpack security so I haven't created any additional "remote_monitor" user.

I followed the error message and tried to add the **xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch** in kibana.yml file but I ended up with the following error :

```
 FATAL  ValidationError: child "xpack" fails because [child "monitoring" fails because [child 
"elasticsearch" fails because ["url" is not allowed]]]
```

Hope anyone can help me in figuring what's wrong.

Comment: You need to make sure that the indenting is correct in your config file as YAML is not really permissive.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT #1**

Solved : problem was due to monitoring not being disabled in the monitoring cluster :

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled": false
  }
}
```

Additional I made a mistake in kibana.yml configuration,
**xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch** should have been  **xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts**

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly the same problem but the root of cause was smth different.

here have a look

okay, i  used to have the same problem.

my kibana did not show monitoring graphs, however
i had monitoring index  index `.monitoring-es-*`  available

the root of problem in my case was that  my master nodes did not have :9200 HTTP socket available from the LAN.  that is  my config on master nodes was:

```
...
transport.host: [ "192.168.7.190" ]
transport.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
http.host: [ "127.0.0.1" ]
...
```

as you can see  HTTP socket is available only from within host.

i didnt want if some one will make HTTP request for masters from LAN because there is
no point to do that.

However as i uderstand Kibana do not only read data from monitoring index

```
index .monitoring-es-*
```

but also  make some requests directly for masters to get some information.

It was exactly why Kibana did not show anything about  monitoring.

After i changed one line in the config on master node as

```
http.host: [ "192.168.0.190", "127.0.0.1" ]
```

immidiately kibana started to show monitoring graphs.

i recreated this expereminet several times.

Now all is working.

Also i want to underline in spite that  now all is fine my monitoring index `.monitoring-es-*`
do NOT have "cluster_stats" documents.

So if your kibana do not show monitoring graphs i suggest

1. check if index .monitoring-es-*  exists
2. check if  your master nodes can serve HTTP requests from LAN